# Upload to Azure Migrate - Error AADSTS16000

Tags: azure, data-migration

I am using the latest version of Data Migration Assistant. Once I finish the assessment of a local SQL Server instance and try to upload the assessment to Azure migrate, I get this error after signing in to my Azure account. I can log into the portal and do everything this is the correct account.

Failed to fetch subscription list from Azure.

AADSTS16000: Either multiple user identities are available for the current request or selected account is not supported for the scenario.

Trace ID: 0d9059b4-0fb2-4acb-902e-a7f196456e00

Correlation ID: 3a3e6876-7ef4-4eca-9e37-714efddf7040
Timestamp: 2023-10-23 11:48:56Z

Comment: Ensure that multiple user identities associated with your Azure account and cached credentials can lead to authentication issues Sign out of your Azure account in the Data Migration Assistant. Try to clear cache and cookies

Comment: In Data Migration Assistant, there is no option to sign out of Azure account.

Comment: still facing issues?

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion from @imran, I cleared the cache and cookies which did not solve my problem but might have contributed to the solution. I am not sure.

I renamed the folder `C:\users\username\AppData\local\DataMigrationAssistant` to `C:\users\username\AppData\local\DataMigrationAssistant_OLD` and reboot solved my problem.